# Enabling In-App purchase for new version of app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

**New version** of my app rejected with the following reason

> We are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of
>   your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review.

Actually I have one In-App purchase with status "Approved".

**Does it mean each new version of my app should have its own In-App purchase item in "Manage In-App Purchases" section?** Initially I thought each new version can share same In-App purchase item(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can keep your IAP items for new versions of your apps. The problem seems to be somewhere else. Maybe you advertise/load an IAP item in the new version of your app that you didn't submit properly?

Comment: I have one clue. In Manage In-App purchase I had one test item which I was using during development only. Haven't deleted that after I submitted my new version. It had `Waiting for screenshot` status. Maybe they thought that's the one which should go along with new version...